# Redirect ping command output to textarea from spring controller using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-web

I want the ping command output to be displayed in the textarea on the webpage. I have my controller method as :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "testInternet.html")
@ResponseBody
public String testInternetConnection() {
    String result = "error";
    String destinationIpAddress = "192.168.1.64";

    //String command = "ping -c 5 ";//for linux
    String command = "ping ";
    String content = "";

    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command+destinationIpAddress);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

            //System.out.println("sending "+s);
            //return s;
            content = content + s + System.lineSeparator();
        }

        System.out.println("Result "+content);
        return content;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "error";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

and my Ajax jquery call is like this

```
$('#testInternet').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("inside test internet Connection");

        $.ajax({
            url : 'testInternet.html',
            type : 'POST',
            processData : false,
            async : false,
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                    $('#ip_output').val(result);//setting output from controller to textarea
                    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.mdl-textfield');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList,function(elem) {
                    elem.MaterialTextfield.checkDirty();
                });
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

    });
```

Here I am getting complete output at once now I want line by line output from controller to be append in textarea as like it displays on command prompt.So can anyone help me with the code how to achieve this.

Comment: what's the problem with you? I think the new line character in textarea and `System.lineSeparator()`  are the same,they should be `\r\n`

Comment: You didn't get my problem.I don't want the controller's complete response in one go.I want line by line to be sent to UI and that will be appended in the textarea which similarly appears as on Command prompt.\r\n or System.lineSeparator is not the problem for me.

Comment: hey your problem is you want to show the result not in one line and want to line by line,why do you think it has nothing to do with `\r\n`?

Comment: Thanks for the input.I replaced the System.lineSeperator with /r/n that is fine,But the output should be sent from while loop.Everytime the s variable should be returned which I commented and which is the output of readline() method.But its not working.To add I want to show it like a live progress of the command.

Comment: you need websocket

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you help me with the code,because I have never implemented this before ?

Comment: no,you can search via google

Comment: Thanks and I would like to integrate it with my current spring boot app.I am using embedded Jetty server for this app.Will it be possible ?

Comment: yeah,but it may cost you some time